# Pip doesn't work in spyder but works in Pycharm

Tags: python, pip, spyder

pip command works in Pycharm, but doesn't work in Spyder.
When I try to use pip in Spyder I get the following message:
"Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
C:\Users\ferna\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\Python\python.exe: No module named pip"

Comment: have you already tried to run the command in another shell? can you also provide an example?

Comment: Seems like you are using the standalone installer. That installation method doesn't have pip available so to use packages outside the ones bundled with the installer you will need to have a way outside Spyder to create and manage python enviroments and use the custom interpreter preference. For more info on that you can check the docs page: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-packages-installer

Answer (score 0):

In addition, also consider that pip is "discouraged" in the last versions of spyder (https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17141).